# Wordpress ,enqueue scripts not bottom , top using constuctor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, wordpress

I have just developed a plugin Ui Slider Filter by price, for wordpress and by no mean i am not a expert coder, learning. So the problem i have faced is , I only wanted to include necessary scripts in specific my plugin pages inside admin and only in the post where the shortcode is called. i had to do some tricky stuff in my classes and couple of script to insert manually using script tag. The function of the plugin is basically user can filter posts by price with dragging a jquery ui slider. You can [see how it works here](http://www.wolopress.com/) and please kindly give me your review.

The main problem was when i use constructor to enqueue script and call , script loads in bottom of page , I want my script to be loaded first then content. I searched so long didnt find any solution.

Just for example

```
Class Slider {
public function __construct (){
     $this->pluginScripts();
   }
public function pluginScripts(){
     //register and enqueue all scripts here.
}
}
```

So my script loads but bottom of the page i want very beginning.

I know how to do this using static function outside of class but that doesn't solve it since i want to load script only when i create instance of this class.

Comment: You have two options: `1.` travel back in time `2.` predict the future. Option `2` is obviously the only realistic one, but even if you are successful it will likely impact performance so heavily that it would be better for you to rethink your design and adjust it such in a way that having the script in the footer is not a problem.

Comment: Actually i am not clear about this whole concept, what is the difference between loading scripts in header and footer , cause i found out for example for a jquery ui slider somtimes if i include scripts in header it works fine , but not when in footer . So how to solve this. Thanks for your comment.